# How make an SSAS Tabular model case sensitive?

Tags: ssas, tabular-model, ssas-2016

I need to make my tabular model case sensitive.

Currently my tabular model is case insensitive, how do I change my existing cube to be case sensitive?

Comment: Have you seen [this](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/jamie_thomson/archive/2010/02/15/mind-that-collation-ssas.aspx)?

Comment: @SqlWorldWide I'm not sure if that applies to Tabular. Either way, it doesn't solve my problem of changing the case sensitivity of my model. My server is already set to case insensitive, but my model does not behave that way.